# Why do I get these packaging errors for my 32-bit build?

Tags: unreal-4

I am trying to package my game in 32 bit for testing purposes. However I keep getting an error during the process. I have no problems packaging 64 bit development versions. Only 32. Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be? Here is the log:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Running AutomationTool...
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Automation.ParseCommandLine: Parsing command line: -ScriptsForProject=C:/dev/projects/ue4/FarkleFriends/FarkleFriends.uproject BuildCookRun -nocompile -nocompileeditor -installed -nop4 -project=C:/dev/projects/ue4/FarkleFriends/FarkleFriends.uproject -cook -stage -archive -archivedirectory=C:/dev/package/debug/windows
 32 -package -clientconfig=Development -ue4exe=UE4Editor-Cmd.exe -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=Win32 -build -utf8output
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): BuildCookRun.SetupParams: Setting up ProjectParams for C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Project.Build: ********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): CommandUtils.Run: Run: C:\dev\UnrealEngine\UE_4.16\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe FarkleFriends Win32 Development -Project=C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject  C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends" -noxg
 e -generatemanifest -NoHotReload
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): CommandUtils.Run: Run: Took 2.7233461s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=0
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): CommandUtils.Run: Run: C:\dev\UnrealEngine\UE_4.16\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe FarkleFriends Win32 Development -Project=C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject  C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends" -noxg
 e -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): UnrealBuildTool: Performing 14 actions (2 in parallel)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): UnrealBuildTool: ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\Binaries\Win32\FarkleFriends.exe
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): UnrealBuildTool: Total build time: 34.18 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): CommandUtils.Run: Run: Took 34.6009145s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Program.Main: ERROR: AutomationTool terminated with exception: AutomationTool.CommandUtils+CommandFailedException: Command failed (Result:5): C:\dev\UnrealEngine\UE_4.16\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe FarkleFriends Win32 Development -Project=C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject  C:\dev\
 projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends" -noxge -NoHotReload -ignorejunk. See logfile for details: 'UnrealBuildTool-2017.07.26-21.49.41.txt' 
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunAndLog(String App, String CommandLine, String Logfile, Int32 MaxSuccessCode, String Input, ERunOptions Options, Dictionary`2 EnvVars, SpewFilterCallbackType SpewFilterCallback)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunAndLog(CommandEnvironment Env, String App, String CommandLine, String LogName, Int32 MaxSuccessCode, String Input, ERunOptions Options, Dictionary`2 EnvVars, SpewFilterCallbackType SpewFilterCallback)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunUBT(CommandEnvironment Env, String UBTExecutable, String CommandLine, String LogName, Dictionary`2 EnvVars)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunUBT(CommandEnvironment Env, String UBTExecutable, FileReference Project, String Target, String Platform, String Config, String AdditionalArgs, String LogName, Dictionary`2 EnvVars)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.UE4Build.BuildWithUBT(String TargetName, UnrealTargetPlatform TargetPlatform, String Config, FileReference UprojectPath, Boolean ForceMonolithic, Boolean ForceNonUnity, Boolean ForceDebugInfo, Boolean ForceFlushMac, Boolean DisableXGE, String InAddArgs, Boolean ForceUnity, Dictionary`2 EnvVars)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.UE4Build.Build(BuildAgenda Agenda, Nullable`1 InDeleteBuildProducts, Boolean InUpdateVersionFiles, Boolean InForceNoXGE, Boolean InUseParallelExecutor, Boolean InForceNonUnity, Boolean InForceUnity, Boolean InShowProgress, Dictionary`2 PlatformEnvVars, Nullable`1 InChangelistNumberOverride, Dictio
 nary`2 InTargetToManifest)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at Project.Build(BuildCommand Command, ProjectParams Params, Int32 WorkingCL, ProjectBuildTargets TargetMask)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at BuildCookRun.DoBuildCookRun(ProjectParams Params)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at BuildCookRun.ExecuteBuild()
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.BuildCommand.Execute()
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.Automation.Execute(List`1 CommandsToExecute, CaselessDictionary`1 Commands)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.Automation.Process(String[] Arguments)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.Program.MainProc(Object Param)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.InternalUtils.RunSingleInstance(Func`2 Main, Object Param)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):    at AutomationTool.Program.Main()
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Program.Main: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
 UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): BUILD FAILED
 PackagingResults:Error: Error Unknown Error
```

**EDIT**
Here is what's in the UnrealBuildTool-....txt log file. The contents of the log for a more recent build with 4.16.3 is the same as the contents of UnrealBuildTool-2017.07.26-21.49.41.txt

```
Performing 14 actions (2 in parallel)
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: 
C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\Binaries\Win32\FarkleFriends.exe
Total build time: 20.26 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
```

**EDIT Part 2**
When I try to run the command

```
C:\dev\UnrealEngine\UE_4.16\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe FarkleFriends Win32 Development -Project=C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject  C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\FarkleFriends.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends" -noxge -NoHotReload -ignorejunk
```

in the cmd prompt I get a Windows error:
[image]

Comment: "C:\dev\projects\ue4\FarkleFriends\Binaries\Win32\FarkleFriends.exe" First, try to rule out the simple scenarios like making sure this directory exists/can be created/can be written to by UBT. In particular, ensure the .exe isn't existing already and accidentally running in the background (check Task Manager). Failing that low-hanging-fruit options, check the content of "UnrealBuildTool-2017.07.26-21.49.41.txt" or post it here, as it may contain additional relevant data.

Comment: This directory is currently empty. I did at one point delete everything in the Binaries folder. I just updated this morning to 4.16.3 so I'll try again making sure the folder is empty.

Comment: I plan to support Android, Windows and Mac. I have been able to successfully package development versions of Android, Mac and Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your system's configuration, check wether it is 32-bit, or 64-bit. Then check the configuration your engine is set to, and if you are using certain development libraries or assets, check theirs to. If  **ANY** one of them does not match the others, there'll be confusing consequences.

This is an example of a common configuration-conflict error in Unreal Engine 4:

```
Error DBG4045: Application configuration (x64) conflicts with library configuration (x86)
```

Keep these points in mind and you'll be able to fix this mess.

**Fix for Edit III**

Place all your required '*.dll' files (including mspdb140.dll) with your Unreal 4 project files.

Comment: This answer confuses me; you imply that there would be an explicit error, yet the log does not show any. You also note that the user should check that their system is not 86 bit; I *assume* you added this to your answer, after not understanding the error you copied in. ***There is no such thing as 86 bit***.

Comment: My os is 64 bit, does that mean I can't package 32 bit software on it?

Comment: Yes, EXACTLY. If your system is 64-bit(x64), make sure EVERYTHING is set to x64. You can't set anything to 32-bit (x86).